# Sudo crontab -e vs crontab -e running command as sudo

Tags: bash, cron

Say I need to run a php script with root permissions every night, is it better practice to run it from the root crontab, or from user with sudo permissions crontab, 'sudoing' in the command. i.e.

In `sudo crontab -e`

```
0 0 * * * /bin/sh -c "/[my_path_to]/php /[my_path_to]/[my_script].php >> /[my_path_to]/cron_log.txt 2>&1"
```

OR

In `crontab -e`

```
 0 0 * * * sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "/[my_path_to]/php /[my_path_to]/[my_script].php >> /[my_path_to]/cron_log.txt 2>&1"
```

Or is there effectively no difference?

Comment: "Better" is the way that you understand and can maintain.

Comment: `sudo crontab -e` is the way things are set up to be used (in order to run scheduled tasks with elevated permissions. But if you make it work the other way, it is also OK. But don't ask me if you have problems to get the password into sudo without compromising the security.

Comment: You don't really need that `sh -c` invocation in root's crontab

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it is better to run a command that needs to be run as root from the crontab of the root user.

Running a command with `sudo` in the user's crontab can technically work, but will require you implement a way to supply the `sudo` password to that command: you will create issues with security.